# Create url rewrites automatically for store view which is created programmatically

Tags: magento, magento2

When new store view is created from magento admin backend, all url rewrites for that store view are created automatically. But when I create programmatically store view from frontend, it's been created but without url rewrites, so basically I will need to create all url rewrites manually but it's impossible since there where about 3000 of them.

I cant find piece of code where magento created those url rewrites automatically after store view is created from admin backend.

Comment: How about saving the store view from the admin panel again without changing anything.. it may trigger the event fro generating URL.

Answer (score 0):

The url generation for catalog happens here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7aa94564d85e408baea01abc5315a0441401c375/app/code/Magento/CatalogUrlRewrite/etc/adminhtml/di.xml#L10
and I assume that this plugin just not dispatched in your case, since you are creating store view from frontend scope

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is true I have found it already and changed the scope but somehow not all product url rewrites and category rewrites are created. Just some of products url rewrites are created and 0 category url rewrites